# Prove that equations $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $y=z\sin(z)$ are bounded smooth curves on $D={(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3;x>0, \frac{\pi}{2}<z<\frac{3\pi}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that equations $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $y=z\sin(z)$ are bounded smooth curves on
$D=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3;x>0, \frac{\pi}{2}<z<\frac{3\pi}{2}\}$

So I put $y$ on other equation and I got $x^2=z^2\cos^2z$. If I consider $D$, where are $x>0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}<z<\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then $x=-z\cos(z)$.

I came to this curve $\vec{r}=(-z\cos(z), z\sin(z), z)$ and I do not know how to prove that this is bounded smooth curve.

Any help?

Comment: What is the definition of smooth curves? Now that you have a parametrization of the curve, showing that it is smooth should not be too difficult.

Comment: You have that $z \in (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$ and a curve parameterized in terms of $z$. Since each of the functions making up that curve are bounded in the closure $\overline{(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})} = [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$, the original curve must also be bounded...